# Scrapy: Finding the correct selector for Lowes Website (included screenshot)

Tags: python, css, scrapy

So here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import LowesspiderItem
from scrapy.http import Request
import requests
import pandas as pd



class LowesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lowes'

    def start_requests(self):

        start_urls = ['https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Alpine-Brushed-Nickel-2-Handle-Widespread-Bathroom-Sink-Faucet-with-Drain/1002623090']

        for url in start_urls:
            yield Request(url,
                        headers={'Cookie': 'sn=2333;'}, #Preset a location
                        meta={'dont_merge_cookies': True, #Allows location cookie to get through
                        'url':url}) #Using to get the product SKU

    def parse(self, response):
        item = LowesspiderItem()



        #get product price
        productPrice = response.css('.sc-kjoXOD iNCICL::text').get()




        item["productPrice"] = productPrice




        yield item
```

---

So this was working last week, but then my spider was deprecated because I assume the website was modified so all my selectors broke. I'm trying to find the new selector for the price but I'm not having any luck.

First I checked if this data was being created dynamically (it's not) so I think using normal scrapy should be fine, correct me if I'm wrong. Here's a screenshot of the page when JavaScript is disabled

[image]

---

So then, I inspected page source and just CTRL + F the price to find the selector that I'd want/need.

[image]

and here's the screenshot as text (if that would help)

```
left"><svg data-test="arrow-left" color="interactive" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="sc-jhAzac boeLhr"><path d="M16.88 5.88L15 4l-8 8 8 8 1.88-1.88L10.773 12z"></path></svg></button><button class="arrowNav right"><svg data-test="arrow-right" color="interactive" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="sc-jhAzac boeLhr"><path d="M8.88 4L7 5.88 13.107 12 7 18.12 8.88 20l8-8z"></path></svg></button></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sc-iQKALj jeIzsl"><div class="sc-gwVKww kbEspX"><div class="sc-esOvli jhvGZy"><div tabindex="0" class="styles__PriceWrapper-sc-1ezid1y-0 cgqauT"><span class="finalPrice"><div class="sc-kjoXOD iNCICL">$314.96 </div><span class="aPrice large" aria-hidden="true"><sup itemProp="PriceCurrency" content="USD" aria-hidden="true">$</sup><span aria-hidden="true">314</span><sup aria-hidden="true">.<!-- --
```

and here is the link for the page source:
view-source:https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Alpine-Brushed-Nickel-2-Handle-Widespread-Bathroom-Sink-Faucet-with-Drain/1002623090

Edit*

---

Looking into the website I thought this selector would make more sense:

```
productPrice = response.css('.primary-font jumbo strong art-pd-contractPricing::text').get()
```

because:
[image]

the price is nested under this selector, but I still get none. I originally thought it was because this is a 'sale' price, so I checked if it was somehow generated through JavaScript, which it is not.

---

### EDIT: So if anyone ever decides to scrape this website, the prices on their products will differ based on location. The cookie I had set was not for the location I had for my local store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the most cursory use of [scrapy shell](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.1/topics/shell.html) would have shown you, `response.css('.sc-kjoXOD iNCICL')` is not the correct CSS selector for your case, since [space means descendant](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#descendant-combinators)

Based on your updated comment about the sale priced pages differing from the other pages, one needs to use a more generic selector. Thankfully, Lowe's seems to honor the https://schema.org/Offer standard which defines a [price itemprop](https://schema.org/price), meaning you have better-than-average confidence the markup won't change from sale page to non-sale page

```python
for offer in response.css('[itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"]'):
    offered_price = offer.css('[itemprop="price"][content]').xpath('@content').get()
```

The asterisk to that comment is that the schema.org standard allows encoding the `itemprop` information in quite a few ways, and their use of the `content=""` attribute is only the *current* way, so watch out for that change

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try this out tomorrow. How did you figure out what selector to use? Was it just from trial and error, for me I've just been guessing when I'd look at the page source. Also why do you have 'div' after .finalPrice?

Comment: A mixture of experience, and knowing HTML and CSS selectors; it's a wise investment to read the [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath), [XPath Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions), and that CSS selectors reference to know what is possible. But always, always look for "semantic" markup since the developer added that, not an autogenerated tool like a minifier. The `div` was because it is the actual element that marks up the price (you were targeting the `div`, too, just with that goofy autogenerated CSS class name)

Comment: Separately, if I were going after that page, I would `response.css('script[type="application/ld+json"]::text').get()` and feed that into `json.loads` since that is already structured data, without all the need to spelunk around in HTML tags

Comment: Also, I just tried .finalPrice and it still returned none did it work for you in scrapy shell?

Comment: I wouldn't have posted an answer I didn't try, but one can clearly see `<span class="finalPrice"` in the code snippet of your own question, so there is obviously something else going on for you

Comment: I tried a different selector for the lowes website on a different item that wasn't on sale and that worked, could there potentially be something wrong with my installation

Comment: just saw the edit, will try this out tomorrow! I'm still confused about the shcema thing. Is that just the standard used for the page for prices and stuff?

Comment: It is for sites that wish to communicate with Google, [as described here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) -- I've periodically seen `ld+json` in the lowes responses, but not always, so I dunno if the requests are being A/B tested or what

Comment: so would I just copy paste the code in for my price right? Also the way you knew it was using shcema was because of the structure of the page source?

Comment: Those attributes (`itemscope`, `itemtype`, `itemprop`) are only used in schema.org, and not in HTML itself, so yes, are a dead giveaway; the `application/ld+json` one is trickier, since Facebook uses it, too, but `"@type": "http://schema.org/Offer"` in the responses that I _have_ seen is similarly an obvious indicator

Comment: You're code worked, but my issue was that price was dependent on location, the cookie I was using was not the one local to me, when I changed that I found out the the price differs between locations! But thank you for the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

```
So then, I inspected page source and just CTRL + F the price to find the selector that I'd want/need.
```

This is not original source - this is html code that already changed as result of javascript.

You need to review **original** html code as scrapy works with raw html 
You can access it by pressing CTRU + U or Right mouse button -> View page source (**not Inspect**)

As result you can see that there is significant difference between original html code and html code changed by javascript.

In original code price occures in several places.
Inside `script` tag. - [some options](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscrapy%5D+script+tag).
Inside `input` tag:

```
price = response.css("input[data-productprice]::attr(data-productprice)").extract_first()
```

Inside `span` tag:

```
 price = response.css('span[itemprop="price"]::attr(content)').extract_first()
```

**UPD**
fullprices and saleprices selectors will be slightly different.

```
saleprice = response.css('span[itemprop="price"]::attr(content)').extract_first()
wasprice_text = response.css('span.art-pd-wasPriceLbl::text).extract_first()
if "$" in wasprice_text:
    fullprice =  wasprice_text.split("$")[-1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response/ explanation! I'm not sure why but I'm still not getting the sale price from the webpage. Like this link over here: https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-42-in-Ducted-Stainless-Steel-Undercabinet-Range-Hood-Common-42-in-Actual-42-in/1000570473 using these selectors only gets me the full price of the item

Comment: thanks I’ll try it out tomorrow! I’ll also get this figured out but is it possible to feed in 2 selectors into on item? Meaning can I populate my item using these selectors by using an or statement?

Comment: Also isn’t the sale price just the same as the span selector from your original answer?